# c++ operator mix using and priority is not what i want

Tags: c++, mysql, operator-overloading

I'm doing some practice about mysql C API encapsulation.
when I decide to write a sql like this.

```
template<class T> C_SQL& operator%(const char* txt)...;
template<class T> C_SQL& operator%(T& t)...;
template<class T> C_SQL& operator,(T& t)...; 

Int kk;
Small jj;

C_SQL sql;
sql % "insert into test_table (tiny_col,short_col) values (" % kk , jj % ")"  ;
```

My plan is that through the overload three operators, I can get a sql text like this:

```
 "insert into test_table (tiny_col,short_col) values (? , ?)" ,
```

and create some bind variables that refer to the address of client var like kk , jj.

My Question is:

due to operator%()'s prioity is higher than that of operator,() , jj stick to ")" by % 
and a complie error complains that class Small has not a operator%.

How to do ? Let char*, kk , jj and char* go into sql object by writing orders.

Comment: The operator precedence cannot be changed. Can't you use different operators? It's not quite clear to me anyway why you have two distinct operators. `,` seems to do almost the same thing as `%`.

Comment: sql % "insert into test_table (tiny_col,short_col) values (" % kk % "," % jj % ")"  ;  //this like a shit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to do?

You can't.  There is no way to change the precedence order of C++ operators.

And even if you could, this is probably a bad idea.  It's considered bad practice to overload random operators like this.

I would suggest sticking to C++ convention, and using `<<` everywhere (as it's not clear to me why you need multiple different operators).

However, it's not clear why you need operator overloading at all here.  To me, this code would be much clearer written as:

```
sql = bind("insert into test_table (tiny_col,short_col) values (?,?)", kk, jj);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. This solution need this technology : we can deal with a lot of objects of any type and any number at one time. how about this form : sql % "insert into test_tbl (col1,col2,col3,col4)" % mysql::list(kk,jj,hh,gg)

Comment: @thomas: That doesn't explain why you need to start overloading weird operators...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

class C_SQL
{
public:
    C_SQL& operator%(const char* txt){
        text_ += txt;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename Tuple>
    C_SQL& operator%( const Tuple& t )
    {
        text_+="values(" ;
        return bind_tuple_helper<Tuple,boost::tuples::length<Tuple>::value>::bind( *this, t );
    }

private:

    template <typename Tuple, size_t size>
    struct bind_tuple_helper {
        static C_SQL& bind( C_SQL& s, const Tuple& t ) {

            //text appends
            s.text_+='?' ;

            //deal with a variable , this is a test
            std::cout<< boost::get<boost::tuples::length<Tuple>::value - size>(t) << std::endl;

            //text appends
            if (size != 1){
                s.text_+=',' ;
            }

            //another var
            return bind_tuple_helper<Tuple,size-1>::bind( s, t );
        }
    };

    //terminator
    template <typename Tuple>
    struct bind_tuple_helper<Tuple,0> {
        static C_SQL& bind( C_SQL& s, const Tuple& t ) {
            s.text_ += ')';
            return s;
        }
    };

    std::string text_;
};



int main() {

    #define  values boost::make_tuple

    int kk=1;
    double jj=2;
    long ll=3;

    C_SQL sql;
    sql % "insert int test_tbl (col1,col2,col3) " % values(kk,jj,ll) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's look more natural ，no redundant question mark '?' . but boost tuple is only support number of varaibles at 10.

Answer (score 0):

I have complete my work. Now I would explain why I don‘t like question mark.

```
bind("select t1.c1,t1.c2 from t1,t2,t3 "
"where t1.c1=? and t1.c4 between ? and ?"
"t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c4=t3.c3 and t2.c3>?" , tt,hh,jj,aa,,rr);

bind("insert into t4 values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", kk,tt,aa,vv,cc,ee,zz,jj,oo);
```

It's more C style and error prone,and you must have a good eyesight
(there are 2 error in them, can you find them out? 
num of ? is not equal to num of var supplied)

I choose a more C++ style.

```
template<class T0,class T1,class T2,class T3>
tuple<T0,T1,T2,T3> values(T0& t0,T1& t1,T2& t2,T3& t3)
{
    using namespace boost;
    return make_tuple(ref(t0),ref(t1),ref(t2),ref(t3));
}

class Small{...};
class Tiny {...};
class String{...};
class Datetime{...};

Small kk;
char buff[32];
String ss(buff,32); //Wrapper. like boost::asio::array
double dd;  //primitive C++ type. does not support NULL field
Double bb;  //Wrapper type. support NULL semantics

C_SQL sql;
sql % "insert int test_tbl (c1,c2,c3,c4)" % values(kk,ss,dd,bb) ;

C_SQL sql2;
sql2 % "select * from t1,t2 where t1.c1=" %kk% 
       "and t1.c2 between" %bb%  " and " %dd% 
       "and t2.c2 = t1.c5"
```

now It's more readble and clear.